# Fitting data to custom equation with 6 unknown parameters

Tags: matlab

I have two large arrays (`Time`, `Amplitude`) which are experimentally sampled data which contains two waves beating together at very similar but different frequencies looking something like this:

[image]

To this i want to fit this equation:

```
(-(A*exp(-t/tau1)).*sin(phi1) - (B*exp(-t/tau2)).*sin(dO.*t+phi2))^2+((A*exp(-t/tau1)).*cos(phi1) + (B*exp(-t/tau2)).*cos(dO.*t+phi2))^2
```

with initial guesses of

```
A = 23.7
B = 33.7
tau1 = 406
tau2 = 401
O1 = 2.0*pi*2789.2
dO = 2.0*pi*0.04
O2 = O1 + dO
phi1 = 1
phi2 = 1.8
fs = 250000
t = Time
```

To produce values of `A,B,tau1,tau2,phi1,phi2`

However im not sure how to fit this many variables to one dataset, I'm fairly new to Matlab and any help would be appreciated

Comment: You may have a look at [`nlinfit`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html)

Comment: Or [search for `nlinfit`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+nlinfit) or [non linear fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+non+linear+fitting) in stackoverflow.